# Event Bubbling from Parent to Child on Target Click

Tags: reactjs, jsx, dom-events

I'm trying to render a table in React and make rows clickable. Table rows may contain cells that have buttons or other clickable elements however and if a table cell contains a clickable element I don't want the row onClick function to be called when the cell element is clicked.

For some reason, the events are propagating in the reverse to what I would expect. From the parent (Row) to the child (Cell) so when I click a checkbox in a cell the order for onClick callbacks is Row -> Checkbox.

Because the more specific onClick handler is called **after** the row's onClick function I've been unable to cancel the event propagation as I initially intended to.

I've had a look into the docs from MDN & react on events but from what I can tell the event should order as follows Cell -> Row

I thought about using a ref to the row & comparing it to the target but would rather not have to store refs for each row visible...

The row code:

```
<TableRow 
    key={keyedItem.key}
    selected={this.isItemSelected(keyedItem.key)}
    hover={true} 
    onClick={(event) => this.handleRowClicked(event, keyedItem)}
>
    {this.renderCheckBox(keyedItem.key)}
    {this.props.renderRowCells(keyedItem.item)}
</TableRow>
```

The renderCheckbox(key) function from above

```
private renderCheckBox(key: string) {
        if (this.multiSelectionMode()) {
            return (
                <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={this.isSelected(key)}
                        onChange={(event, checked: boolean) => { console.log(event.target); this.changeItemSelection(key, checked); }}
                   />
                </TableCell>
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Or is this working as intended?

Comment: Hi Liam, just wrote you an answer, let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do to prevent this sort of event-bubbling is to define a switch-case. You can filter the target that is causing the event by its className then apply your logic for each case.

Here is a codesandbox for you to see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-waterfall-u7b87

### Parent

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cells: [
      { value: 1, selected: false },
      { value: 2, selected: false },
      { value: 3, selected: false }
    ]
  };
  handleClickEvents = event => {
    var target = event.target.className;
    switch (target) {
      case "parent":
        return console.log(target);
      case "child":
        return this.findCheckedInput(event);
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  findCheckedInput = event => {
    const updatedCells = this.state.cells.map(cell => {
      if (cell.value == event.target.value) {
        return {
          ...cell,
          selected: !cell.selected
        };
      } else {
        return cell;
      }
    });

    this.setState(
      {
        cells: updatedCells
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  };

  renderChildren = () => {
    const { cells } = this.state;
    return cells.map(item => {
      return (
        <Child
          key={item.value}
          handleClick={this.handleClickEvents}
          value={item.value}
          selected={item.selected}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="parent"
        style={{ background: "green" }}
        onClick={this.handleClickEvents}
      >
        {this.renderChildren()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

### Child

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.props.handleClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        className="child"
        onChange={this.handleOnClick}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.props.selected}
        value={this.props.value}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```